# Videoplayer.Markers is Not a function error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, video.js, markers

I want to add markers to my videojs player dynamically. I am trying to videojs-markers plugin. but I get error

> Videoplayer.markers is not a function

```
 <video id="vEpisodePlayer"
               class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered "
               controls="controls"
               preload="auto">
 </video>
 @section Scripts{
<script src="~/js/video.js" defer="defer"></script>
@*<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-ads/6.9.0/videojs.ads.min.js" integrity="sha512-ff4Rc39SC+LyUOUEKUvQ5VW/BMtzy+p3/zN+zB/VloiEfFpkY4JseoJC2TtwJTnn2PrSsm+dvSW6S4yV6uADUA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>*@
<script src="~/js/videojs-seek-buttons.min.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs-markers.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/Development/videoPlayer.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/Development/videoDetail.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

javascript:

```
Videoplayer = videojs("#vEpisodePlayer", options, function onPlayerReady() {
    this.fill(false);
    this.seekButtons({
        forward: 10,
        back: 10
    });
    

});

Videoplayer.src({ type: 'video/mp4', src: source });

Videoplayer.markers({
    markerStyle: {
        'width': '190px',
        'border-radius': '2px',
        'background-color': 'orange'
    }
});
```

How can I fix this error and add markers to my videojs player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means the Video.js plugin has not been registered. You have used `defer` on some scripts but not the markers plugin script. You should defer that one too, otherwise it is executing before `videojs` exists and it's not possible to register a plugin against it.